# Getting error "ClassNotFoundException" even after scribe for oauth in restassured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, scribe

Added Scribe in pom file which is used for oauth in restassured as per the documenation, Even then getting the error

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.github.scribejava.core.model.AbstractRequest`

How to resolve this error. Added below dependency of scribe in pom file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Below mentioned the code written to make the request.

```
 Response response  = given().auth().
                         oauth("c", "r", "3", "r1").
                         post("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json").
                         then().
                         assertThat().
                         statusCode(200).
                         log().all().extract().response();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error message then i changed the version of ScribeJava 4.0.0 to scribejava-apis 2.5.3 and scribejava-core 2.5.3
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [javadocs](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.scribejava/scribejava-core): [`AbstractRequest`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.scribejava/scribejava-core/4.0.0/com/github/scribejava/core/model/AbstractRequest.html) was deprecated in ScribeJava 4.0.0 and it was removed in the version 4.1.0. So it longer exists in ScribeJava 5.5.0 and [`OAuthRequest`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.scribejava/scribejava-core/5.5.0/com/github/scribejava/core/model/OAuthRequest.html) must be used instead.